# QEMU SDL_Init failed: No available video device

Tags: virtualization, qemu, sdl

Total Linux NOOB looking for advice:

I'm trying to run a 64bit application on a 32bit PC using QEMU user mode. I have compiled qemu from source, all good, but when I want to start the application (qemu-x86_64 myapp) I get:

```
SDL_Init failed: No available video device
```

I have used MultiArch to install libSDL2:amd64 and I also have libsdl installed. I have searched the forums high and low but almost everybody is speaking of qemu-system-x86_64 which is a full system emulation (not what I'm interested in)

For test purpose I installed xterm:amd64 but that doesn't seem to work either:

```
qemu_x86_64 /usr/bin/xterm 
Xt error: Can't open display :0
```

When I do `./configure` the QEMU build it does say that SDL=Yes so I'm very confused.

Comment: I might be totally wrong here, but... I thought 64bits-compiled softwares were using specific CPU calls that aren't present on a 32bit CPU, making (even in case of VM) them absolutely unusable on 32 bits CPU ?